# Encode String to audio file for storage Android

Tags: android, audio, encoding, android-mediarecorder

I've written the following code so that the output file (the path leading to an audio file) is converted to a byte array, then converted to a string using base64EncodedString. However I am having difficulty writing code to convert it back to an audioFile so that it can be played. Here is my code to encode the audio to a string:

```
String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ filepath + ".3gp";;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(outputFile));
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int n;
    while((n = fis.read(buf))!=-1){
        bos.write(buf,0,n);
}
String base64EncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Help writing the code to turn it back into an audio file (media recorder) would be great.

Comment: Any luck?
Same issue with me..